# Not able to close modal window by function

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using modal like

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' visible="successmessage">
    <form role="form">
            Success ful result.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="closesuccessmessage()" >Ok</button>
    </form>
</modal>
```

I have a directive on modal..

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('abc.directives', [])
.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ modalTitle }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.modalTitle = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };  
  });
```

in my angular controller i have created function like below

```
$scope.closesuccessmessage = function()
{
  $scope.successmessage = false;
}
```

But it does not have any effect. How can i make it work. As it is very important for me to control this from a function.  Modal opens up on true value, but does not close on false value.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or jsFiddle reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use like above you're doing. You should call modal `hide` function to hide a modal. Try below snippet

```
$scope.closesuccessmessage = function()
{
  $("#successmessage").modal('hide');
}
```

**EDIT**

It's not like that you can't use scope values in your HTML. If your controller is same, you can access it easily. I changed your HTML. Please try below one

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' data-ng-show="successmessage">
```

instead

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' visible="successmessage">
```

Comment: This works. But why is that scope value not effecting the visiblity property??

Comment: `ng-show` works on `true` `false`. If it found false then it will hide the snippet and if variable contain true in it, it will show the snippet. You need to put `successmessage = true` when you want to show your modal.

Comment: If i use <modal title="ADD NEW SEASON" id='showAddSeason' visible="true"> it works and if i use <modal title="ADD NEW SEASON" id='showAddSeason' ng-show="true"> it does not

Comment: `<modal title="ADD NEW SEASON" id='showAddSeason' visible="{{successmessage}}">` You should try this snippet in your case. You're not passing controller scope's value in `ng` directives. So you need to manually pass the value by using `{{` variable `}}`

Comment: Will you please create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

In order for angularjs to bind variable to view outside of properties expecting expressions you must use brackets.

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' visible="{{successmessage}}">
    <form role="form">
            Success ful result.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="closesuccessmessage()" >Ok</button>
    </form>
</modal>
```

However I'm not sure visible is a valid property in HTML. If you want to hide modal using variable you could use ng-show and set success message variable in controller

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' ng-show="successmessage">
    <form role="form">
            Success ful result.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="closesuccessmessage()" >Ok</button>
    </form>
</modal>
```